# Mapping list of stings to 0 in Pandas Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, mapping

I am trying to study the effects of Alcohol and Drugs in car accidents using an Open BigQuery dataset. I have my dataset ready to go and am just refining it further. I want to categorize the string entries in the pandas columns.

The data frame is over 11,000 entries and there are about 44 unique values in each column. However, I just want to categorize only the entries which say 'Alcohol Involvement' and 'Drugs (Illegal)' to 1 and respectively. I want to map any other entry to 0.

I have created a list of all the entries which I don't care about and want to get rid of and they are in a list as follows:

```
list_ign  = ['Backing Unsafely',
   'Turning Improperly', 'Other Vehicular',
   'Driver Inattention/Distraction', 'Following Too Closely',
   'Oversized Vehicle', 'Driver Inexperience', 'Brakes Defective',
   'View Obstructed/Limited', 'Passing or Lane Usage Improper',
   'Unsafe Lane Changing', 'Failure to Yield Right-of-Way',
   'Fatigued/Drowsy', 'Prescription Medication',
   'Failure to Keep Right', 'Pavement Slippery', 'Lost Consciousness',
   'Cell Phone (hands-free)', 'Outside Car Distraction',
   'Traffic Control Disregarded', 'Fell Asleep',
   'Passenger Distraction', 'Physical Disability', 'Illness', 'Glare',
   'Other Electronic Device', 'Obstruction/Debris', 'Unsafe Speed',
   'Aggressive Driving/Road Rage',
   'Pedestrian/Bicyclist/Other Pedestrian Error/Confusion',
   'Reaction to Other Uninvolved Vehicle', 'Steering Failure',
   'Traffic Control Device Improper/Non-Working',
   'Tire Failure/Inadequate', 'Animals Action',
   'Driverless/Runaway Vehicle']
```

What could I do to just map 'Alcohol Involvement' and 'Drugs (Illegal)' to 1 and respectively and set everything in the list shown to 0

Comment: Why do you need a list of things you don't want? Just keep a (shorter) list of things you want, then set everything else to 0. Isn't that the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your source column is named `Crime`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Illegal'] = np.where(df['Crime'].isin(['Alcohol Involvement', 'Drugs']), 1, 0)
```

Or,

```
df['Crime'] = df['Crime'].isin(['Alcohol Involvement', 'Drugs']).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, while the above-mentioned methods work fine. However, they were not tagging all the categories I wanted to remove later on. So, I used this method,

```
for word in list_ign:
    df = df.replace(str(word), 'Replace')
```